# In a descriptor, does __call__ have access to the class where the decorator is being used?

Tags: python, decorator

Consider the following code:

```
class MyCustomDescriptor:
    def __init__(self,foo):
        self._foo = foo

    def __call__(self,decorated_method):
        # Here's my question...  Is there any way to get a reference to the
        # type (ClassA or ClassB) here?
        return self

    def __get__(self,instance,type):
        # Clearly at this point I can get the type of the class.
        # But it's too late, I would have liked
        # to get it back in __call__.
        return 10

class ClassA:
    @MyCustomDescriptor(foo=1)
    def some_value(self): pass

class ClassB:
    @MyCustomDescriptor(foo=1)
    def some_value(self): pass
```

The reason I'd like to get a reference to the class is that I'd like to add some static data to the class with the decorated function/method.  I realize this is somewhat atypical but for what I'm doing, it would be helpful.

ANSWER - Can't be done.  Based on one of the responses below I inspected the stack from within call and was able to get the fully qualified class where the descriptor is being used (ClassA or ClassB in my example).  But you *can't* turn this into a type/class because the type/class is still being parsed (or whatever the right term is in python).  In other words, python comes across ClassA and starts parsing it.  While parsing it, it comes across the descriptor and invokes init and call on the descriptor.  ClassA still hasn't finished getting parsed.  Therefore regardless of the fact that you can get a fully qualified module/class name from within call, you can't turn it into a type.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the decorator in the first place?

Comment: `The reason I'd like to get a reference to the class is that I'd like to add some static data to the class with the decorated function/method` You should decorate the class then, not the method.

Comment: I could but it's less readable.  Consider the value of putting the metadata with the method like this: @zwave_field(byte_position=2,description="Status")
def status(self): pass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the point where the decorator is being applied, `some_value` is just a function, not a method. So, no, there is no way for the function to know it is associated with a particular class.

Two alternatives are:

- Pass the class name to `MyCustomDescriptor` (along with `foo`), or
- Use a class decorator to create the descriptor `some_value`.

---

The class decorator might look something like this:

```
def register(method_name,foo):
    def class_decorator(cls):
        method=getattr(cls,method_name)
        class MyCustomDescriptor(object):
            def __get__(self,instance,type):
                result=method(instance)
                return '{c}: {r}'.format(c=cls.__name__,r=result)
        setattr(cls,method_name,MyCustomDescriptor())
        return cls
    return class_decorator

@register('some_value',foo=1)
class ClassA:
    def some_value(self):
        return 10
```

For example, running

```
a=ClassA()
print(a.some_value)
```

yields

```
ClassA: 10
```

Comment: The information I need is in the descriptors, not the class decorator.  But you're making me think that a hybrid approach would be to decorate the class and in the class decorator, iterate over the function/method descriptors, grabbing their data.  Then I could put the static data on the class that I want to.  I'll try this.

Comment: @MatthewLund: Whatever you're doing sounds way overly complex.

Comment: When you build a plugin patterned-program you have to get through some of this complex stuff but the benefit is that the plugin classes themselves can be greatly simplified.  So it's a question of where you're spending your work.

Answer (score 1):

Well... there is one way I can think of, but it qualifies as what I like to call "Python voodoo" which means it's accessing features of Python that should not be used in normal programming. So **think carefully before you do this**. It's also implementation-dependent, so don't rely on this if you want your code to be portable to other Python interpreters (other than CPython). That being said:

When the descriptor's `__call__` method is invoked, you can access the interpreter stack using `inspect.stack()`. The second stack frame in the returned list represents the context from which `__call__` was invoked. Part of the information included in that stack frame is the context name, which is normally a function name, but in this case `__call__` wasn't invoked from inside a function, it was invoked from inside a class, so the context name will be the name of the class.

```
import inspect

class MyCustomDescriptor:
    def __call__(self,decorated_method):
        self.caller_name = inspect.stack()[1][3]
        return self
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, my co-worker and I considered this.  It would work but it's certainly voodoo like you said :)

Comment: As a follow-up, I tried this and couldn't get it work.  That is to say, the stack frame gave me access to the class name and the physical file path that it's in.  I used the file path to figure out the module and successfully invoked __import__ to get the module.  But the problem was that the module didn't have an attribute representing the class.  I'm wondering if the reason is that the descriptor must be processed for python to finish loading the class.  But within the descriptor we're trying to access the class.  Maybe the class can't be loaded at this point.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Ah, OK, I only tested it as far as accessing the name of the class, not actually accessing the class object itself. That wouldn't work because the class object is not defined until the end of the `class` block, but the descriptor gets called before that block finishes executing.